# Issues Starting Node App in Docker container on M1 MacBook

Tags: docker, apple-m1, nodemon

We have an app that we've been running using Docker. When I returned from vacation the app would no longer run on my machine. We've walked back all changes that have happened since my departure and still no progress.

The client app appears to start fine, but the server does not. Nodemon is called, calls the build script but nothing happens from there. The app doesn't crash, nor does nodemon restart or give any form of feedback.

We've tried defining the arch in our compose and Dockerfile and there's been no change. Things seem to break down around nodemon being called, but there's no feedback and I'm unsure how to get better information to move forward on this.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by specifying the platform flag:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with M1 macbook. Running `docker-compose up` would hang creating a container, seconds would run but never finish. Adding correct platform like this to docker-compose.yml made it work: `platform: linux/amd64`